# Vim function to insert a Python import if it hasn't been imported yet

Tags: python, vim, plugins, import

I currently have a Vim function that will wrap selected text within a `time.time()` block so that I can quickly time things.

I would like for the function to also go to the top of the file, check if `import time` exists or not, and insert `import time` only if it doesn't exist already.

Is there any way to check if text exists or not in Vim?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I currently have. It works, but please do post your own solution if you have something better!

Also, note that the line that has the `^M` is formed by pressing `Ctrl-V` and then the `Enter` button in insert mode (Stack Overflow doesn't copy it over very well).

```
" easily wrap the selected text in a time.time() statement for quick timing
fun! s:PythonTiming(line1, line2)

    " mark line one  &&  keep track of lines selected
    execute 'normal!' 'me'
    let l:numDiff = a:line2 - a:line1

    " start timing
    execute 'normal!' 'Ostart = time.time()'

    " end timing
    while line('.') < a:line2 + 1
        execute 'normal!' 'j'
    endwhile
    execute 'normal!' 'oend = time.time()'
    execute 'normal!' 'oprint; print("end - start: "); print(end - start)'

    " add the `import time` statement if not already imported
    let match = search('import time', 'nw')
    if match == 0
        silent! execute 'normal!' 'gg/import/^M'
        execute 'normal!' 'oimport time'
    endif

    " go back to the initial mark
    execute 'normal!' '`e'

endfun
command! -range Time :call s:PythonTiming(<line1>, <line2>)
```